# Receber post de uma view para outra view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho duas Views.

1. `Index`
2. `Assincrona`

Quando acesso a `index`, ele chama a *View* `Assincrona` e fica um gif carregando até a página toda (`Assincrona`) ser carregada e mostra na *View*.

**Códigos Controller**

```
public ActionResult Assincrona()
    {
        DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
        mes = Convert.ToInt32(data.Month) - 2;
        dadosCarteiraPGC(2016, mes, null);

        return PartialView("Assincrona", carteiraPGC);
    }

public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Códigos View**

```
<div class="partialContents" data-url="/Consulta/Assincrona">
            <div class="mensagem"><img src="~/Images/indicator.white.gif"/><p>Carregando ... </p></div>
</div>
```

**Códigos JS**

```
var site = site || {};
site.baseUrl = site.baseUrl || "";

$(document).ready(function (e) {    
$(".partialContents").each(function(index, item) {
    var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
    if (url && url.length > 0 ) {
        $(item).load(url);
    }
});

$("a.nav").click(function() {
    $("body").html("");
});
});
```

Está funcionando perfeito até eu precisar receber dados via post.

Recupero o valor do mês via `[HttpPost]Index`, mas não consigo passar para `Assincrona` quando ela é chamada via *View*.

Usar `TempData[]` seria um bom modo de resolver esse problema ou existe outra forma de fazer?

Answer (score 1):

> Usar `TempData[]` seria um bom modo de resolver esse problema ou existe outra forma de fazer?

Não. O problema é outro aqui. Você está fazendo um `load` de algo que não tem e que não pode receber argumentos. Aliás, `load` não serve para isso que você quer.

O correto seria ou passar esses argumentos por `GET` ou por `POST`. Possivelmente você quer algo mais restrito, então o recomendável é `POST`. A chamada, portanto, precisa ser usando [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
var site = site || {};
site.baseUrl = site.baseUrl || "";

$(document).ready(function (e) {    
    $(".partialContents").each(function(index, item) {
        var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
        if (url && url.length > 0 ) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: { campo1: "Valor1", campo2: 1 } // Coloque aqui seus campos
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
        }
    });

    $("a.nav").click(function() {
        $("body").html("");
    });
});
```

Feito isso, escreva uma *Action* que aceite `[HttpPost]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Assincrona(ParametrosViewModel viewModel) { ... }
```